# Operator new overloading c++, handling failure without exception

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I'm working on a project that doesn't use exceptions, and should stay that way.
I overloaded (overrid will be more correct maybe) new operator in order to use my own memory manager. In my memory manager, in case of a failure in allocation - NULL is being returned.
Now altough new operator returned NULL, the constructor is being called and then I get a seg fault because I didn't have memory allocated.
The functionalitty that I'd want is that if the new operator returned NULL, then the constructor shouldn't be called (and I will check afterwards if the object was successfuly initialized).

I want it to work something like this:

```
myObject = new object(...);
if (NULL == myObject)
    printf("error")
else
    do something
```

Thanks!

Comment: The [`operator new` and `operator new[]` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) only allocate memory, it's the compiler which creates the code to call the possible constructor when you use the `new` operator. Returning a null pointer (`nullptr` or alternatively `0`) is the correct behavior on failure.

Comment: new object(...) allocates memory and calls constructor. I want it to call constructor only if the allocation succeeded. I know about the nothrow option which is what I need, but how do I make something like this when overloading?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Only if you declare your allocation function as non-throwing via `noexcept` or `throw()`, see [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]p3 -- it is not clear to me if that's implied when disabling exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

You need to invoke `new (nothrow)`, something like this:

```
myObject* = new (std::nothrow) myObject(...);
```

Then, instead of overriding the regular `operator new` you need to override the one(s) that take `std::nothrow_t`.  For more on that, see here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/

The regular `operator new` without `nothrow` is not supposed to return null on failure, rather it should throw.  Since you aren't allowed to throw, you cannot implement those operators (unless by calling `abort()` on failure or something similar).

Finally, it might help to completely disable exceptions during compilation.  I would hope this sort of mistake would have been caught then (I'm not sure about this).

Comment: This is not the only way to do it, especially if you're writing your own `operator new`. [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]p3 *"If an allocation function that has a non-throwing exception specification fails to allocate storage, it shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception of a type that would match a handler of type `std::bad_alloc`."*

Comment: @dyp: How is "an allocation function that has a non-throwing exception specification" different from the `operator new` that takes `std::nothrow_t`?  It seems to me that the `nothrow` one is `noexcept`, and the "regular" one is not, so I'm not entirely sure what you're driving at.

Comment: `std::nothrow_t` is not an exception specification. Also, I have removed a reference in my quotation: after *"non-throwing exception speficiation"*, [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]p3 refers to [except.spec], which is the section about "Exception specifications". While you cannot replace the default `operator new(size_t)` with a `noexcept` one, you can write custom allocation functions for class types which are `noexcept`.

Comment: In C++03, the same paragraph was: *"If an allocation function
declared with an empty exception-specification (15.4), `throw()`, fails to allocate storage, it shall return a null pointer."*

Comment: even when i'm overriding new (std::nothrow), the constructor is still being called. any ideas about what I might be doing wrong? the function returns NULL.

Comment: @user3445972 Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE). Here's an example of how to replace allocation and deallocation functions such that they can fail by returning a null pointer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcb4aa772cdfd89e

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the solution was to add 'throw()' at the end of the function decleration of new.

```
void* operator new (size_t size) throw()
```

Could be done in either in the regular new or new (nothrow). In my imlpementation adding it to the regular new caused the desired effect that any 'new' call will be able to return NULL upon failure.

There is also an option of using '--force_new_nothrow' flag in compilation.

more about both can be found
[here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14267.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want provide a custom, class-specific allocation function and not overload the new operator in the global namespace.

#### tl;dr

Since C++11: Declare your custom `operator new` with `noexcept` and everything works fine.

```
void* T::operator new (size_t size) noexcept;
```

#### Full answer

While the currently accepted answer given by John proposes a working solution, it implies that the `std::nothrow` tag is necessary and this can't be done without it, which is wrong.

This answer is just the (correct) comment of @dyp, expanded into a full answer and with current quotes from the standard.

The [C++11 standard](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says in [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation], paragraph 3:

> If an allocation function declared with a non-throwing exception-specification (15.4) fails to allocate storage, it shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type std::bad_alloc (18.6.2.1).

Over the years, this sentence has been rewritten, but something semantically equivalent has been in C++14, C++17 and C++20. [The current working draft for C++23](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/n4885.pdf) has this paragraph in [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]:

> An allocation function that has a non-throwing exception specification (14.5) indicates failure by returning a null pointer value. Any other allocation function never returns a null pointer value and indicates failure only by throwing an exception (14.2) of a type that would match a handler (14.4) of type std::bad_alloc (17.6.4.1).

The "non-throwing exception specification" is defined in [except.spec]. A function has this specification if you add `noexcept` as a suffix to the declaration. Thus, the code given in the question can work totally fine, but the custom new operator has to be declared with `noexcept`:

```
void* T::operator new (size_t size) noexcept;
```

Alternatively, up to C++17, using `throw()` instead of `noexcept` worked too, but it has been deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++20. It was the way to go before C++11. OP ended up using this according to their own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this by hand, ie.

```
object * create_object(MemoryManager & mem, ...) {
   void * chunk = mem.get_memory_for_object();
   if (chunk == NULL) return NULL;
   return new (chunk) object(...); // inplace new 
}
```